# Array of Nested Type: Why Does the Compiler Complain?

Tags: swift

```
class ClassA {
    class ClassB {
    }
}
let compiles: [ClassA.ClassB]
let doesNotCompile = [ClassA.ClassB]()
```

Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:109:22: error: invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[ClassA.ClassB.Type]'
let doesNotCompile = ClassA.ClassB
                     ^              ~~

Comment: Seems like a bug. Try the latest Swift toolchain or file a bug at http://bugs.swift.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, it works with this syntax:

```
let arrayOfClassB: [ClassA.ClassB] = []
```

but the `[]()` syntax works if we declare a `typealias`:

```
typealias InnerClass = ClassA.ClassB
let arrayOfAliasesOfClassB = [InnerClass]()
```

So I'd say it's a bug, `let arrayOfClassB = [ClassA.ClassB]()` should also work without needing a typealias.

**Update**: there's already [an opened bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/19812302) about this at Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why the shorthand syntax does not work. However the compiler seems to like the extended syntax

```
let list = Array<ClassA.ClassB>()
```

Answer (score -1):

compiles is an array of type ClassA.ClassB

In doesNotCompile you are trying to use an array as a function. Didn't you mean:

```
let doesNotCompile = ClassA.ClassB()
```

Comment: No, OP is trying to create an empty array of the specific type, he is not trying to create an instance of either ClassA or ClassB