# Swift 2D Array Generic Extension - issue accessing 2nd dimension

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I'm trying to transform the following function into a generic extension for 2D Arrays.

```
func rotate(_ input: [[Int]]) -> [[Int]]
{
  let length = input[0].count
  var value = Array(repeating: [Int](), count: length)
  for index in 0 ..< length
  {
    value[index] = input.map { $0[index] }.reversed()
  }
  return value
}
```

I'm specifically stumped as to how to specify the constraints to allow me to access the second dimension. Here's a failed attempt:

```
extension Array where Element: Collection, Element.Iterator.Element: Collection
{
  private func rotate()
  {
    let count = self[0].count // Element.IndexDistance instead of Int

    // Expression type 'Array<Element>' is ambiguous without more context
    var returnValue = Array(repeating: Element, count: 11)
    for index in 0 ..< count // Element.IndexDistance instead of Int
    {
      returnValue[index] = self.map { $0[index] }.reversed()
    }
    return returnValue
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that your extension is for 2D arrays – it just knows that it's for arrays of collections. Therefore the associated types `IndexDistance` and `Index` aren't necessarily `Int`.

The solution therefore is to constrain your extension so that the `Element`'s `IndexDistance` and `Index` *are* of type `Int`. This will let you form the range `0..<count`, as `count` will now be of type `Int` (`IndexDistance`) – and you will be able to subscript the elements within the `map(_:)` with `Int`s (as the subscript expects an `Index`).

<sup>(This will be trivial to do once [concrete same-type requirements](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#concrete-same-type-requirements) are supported, as you could simply constrain the `Element` to be an `Array`, however this is not yet possible.)</sup>

You should also note that your constraint `Element.Iterator.Element: Collection` is incorrect, as that'll constrain the extension to 3D arrays of collections (An array where the element is a collection, where the elements of that collection are a collection).

Finally, you may have to define a `typealias` to represent the 'inner element' type of the 2D array, as Swift currently has [some limitations when working with nested types directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773355/array-of-nested-type-why-does-the-compiler-complain), for example when creating an empty 2D array of that type.

Therefore, a working version of your current method would look something like this:

```
extension Array where Element: Collection, Element.Index == Int, Element.IndexDistance == Int {

    private func rotate() -> [[Element.Iterator.Element]] {

        typealias InnerElement = Element.Iterator.Element

        // in the case of an empty array, simply return an empty array
        if self.isEmpty { return [] } 
        let length = self[0].count

        var returnValue = [[InnerElement]](repeating: [InnerElement](), count: length)
        for index in 0..<length {
            returnValue[index] = self.map{ $0[index] }.reversed()
        }
        return returnValue
    }
}
```

Which, as [@MartinR points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179660/swift-2d-array-generic-extension-issue-accessing-2nd-dimension#comment65702002_39180014), could be simplified considerably by using a nested `map(_:)`, eliminating the need of a `typealias` as we no longer need to create a 'result' array:

```
private func rotate() -> [[Element.Iterator.Element]] {

    if self.isEmpty { return [] }
    let length = self[0].count

    return (0..<length).map { index in
        self.map { $0[index] }.reversed()
    }
}
```

---

Although note that the constraining of your extension to only work with `Int` indices isn't strictly necessary (however makes no practical difference as you're only intending to use this with 2D arrays). Another alternative is to just iterate directly over the inner collection's `indices`.

In order to do this, you simply have to constrain your extension so that the inner collection's `Indices` have `Element`s of the same type as the `Index` of the collection (in the case of an `Array`, `Indices` is a `CountableRange<Int>`):

```
extension Array where Element: Collection, Element.Indices.Iterator.Element == Element.Index {
    private func rotate() -> [[Element.Iterator.Element]] {

        if self.isEmpty { return [] }

        return self[0].indices.map { index in
            self.map { $0[index] }.reversed()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `return (0..<length).map { index in self.map{ $0[index] }.reversed() }`, without creating an empty result array first.

Comment: @MartinR Fantastic point, thanks for mentioning it – I have edited my answer to include this :)

Comment: Thanks for the revision Hamish, perfect. TIL

Comment: @AfricanSwift Happy to help :)

Comment: @Hamish In general, avoid `for index in 0..<length`. If you need the index, go for `for i in array.indicies`. If you need values, go for `for value in array`, and if you need both, use `for (i, value) in array.enumerated()`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov In general, I agree with you. Although in this particular case, being able to use `self[0].indices` requires a separate set of constraints for the extension (which I demonstrate in my last example).