# Swift method on generic 2 dimensional Array

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to create an extension method on the Array type when the array is a 2 dimensional array, ex. `[[Int]]`, but the type should be generic.  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
extension Array [where Element : ???] {

  public func transposed() -> ??? {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39180014.

Comment: I did.  It is illuminating.  But the answer is simpler.  Also my question is simpler to understand and brief.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Swift 4.

```
extension Array where Element: Collection {

    public func transposed() -> [[Element.Iterator.Element]] {
        var result : [[Element.Iterator.Element]] = [[]]
        for row in self {
            for (y,column) in row.enumerated() {
                while (result.count <= y) {
                    result.append([])
                }
                result[y].append(column)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Then also unit testing passed:

```
func testTransposed() {
    XCTAssertEqual([[1]].transposed(), [[1]])
    XCTAssertEqual([[1,2,3],[4,5]].transposed(), [[1,4],[2,5],[3]])
    XCTAssertEqual([[4,1],[5,2],[3]].transposed(),[[4,5,3],[1,2]])
    XCTAssertEqual([[1,2,3]].transposed(), [[1],[2],[3]])
    XCTAssertEqual([[1],[2],[3]].transposed(),[[1,2,3]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
extension Array
{
   func transposed<T>() -> [[T]] where Element == Array<T>
   {
      return self[0].indices.map{ i in self.map{$0[i]} }
   }
}

let a = [ [1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9] ]
for r in a.transposed() {print(r)}

// [1, 4, 7]
// [2, 5, 8]
// [3, 6, 9]
// note that the matrix cannot be sparse
```