# Swift error: cannot call value of non-function type '[T.Iterator.Element.Type]'

Tags: swift, generics, iterator, swift-playground, swift-protocols

This is the working code from swift Playgrounds - Generics:

```
func makeArray<T>(item: T, numberOfTimes: Int) -> [T] {
    var result = [T]()
    // some code here
    return result
}
```

Pay attention to the line

```
var result = [T]()
```

It works correctly here. However, in the next example with the similar idea

```
func anyCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U)
        -> [T.Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
        var result = [T.Iterator.Element]()
        // some code here
        return result
}
```

it crashes with an error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Generics.xcplaygroundpage:28:42: error: cannot call value of non-function type '[T.Iterator.Element.Type]'
    var result = [T.Iterator.Element]()
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

**The fix for this** is to create an array either this way:

```
var result: [T.Iterator.Element] = []
```

or this:

```
var result = Array<T.Iterator.Element>()
```

However, I don't understand what's the difference between these examples. I guess it might be a Swift bug similar to [this one](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-773). Are there any ideas on why does it behave in such a weird way?

Comment: Also observed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773355/array-of-nested-type-why-does-the-compiler-complain. – But what are you actually asking? You already found out that it is a *bug.*

Comment: It's exactly the same as [the bug you link to](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-773) – see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/39041712/2976878

Comment: The big that I'm referring to is about "Using Array initializer syntax **with nested types**" so even though it's similar it might be another problem. I'm trying to understand if it's really a bug or just a language peculiarity that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: And besides my curiosity, I think it will be useful to have such question *with a solution* for those who might face this problem.

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug to me `[Type]()` is supposed to be syntactic sugar for `Array<Type>()` It doesn't work in this circumstance, so it is a bug. Short of fixing the bug, your question already contains two completely fine fixes.